# Subscript Out of Range Error Making LastRow an Integer

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to store `LastRow` as an `Integer` but keep getting "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range". The sheet I need it to work in is "Self-Service Report". The code I'm using is:

```
Dim LastRow As Integer

LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Self-Service Report").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: `Dim LastRow as Long`... but the error sounds like it's related to the sheet name. Using `Integer` could cause an Overflow error.

Comment: hi. the sheet name seems to be wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle, therefore row counting variables need to be `Long`
2. `Rows.Count` should specify to the worksheet
3. Your worksheet name `Self-Service Report` seems to be wrong. Check for spelling and extra spaces.
4. `Worksheets` is not equal to `Sheets`. `Worksheets` contain only worksheets but `Sheets` can also contain `Charts` for example.

---

```
Dim LastRow As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Self-Service Report")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

Comment: Hmmm... I put that line of code in, checked the spelling/spaces, but I'm still getting the error

Comment: @Conor you get the out of range in the `With …` line? If yes then the worksheet name does *definitly* not exist in `ThisWorkbook` (which is the workbook the code is running in).

Comment: Ah, I found the issue. I was doing this in my Personal.XLSB    Is there a way to make the code work with it in the personal file, rather than the actual workbook?

Comment: If you have the code in `Personal.xlsb` and you want to run it in the active workbook use `ActiveWorkbook` (the one which has focus) instead of `ThisWorkbook` (the one the code is in).

Comment: It works now. Thank you!